# UIImageView view can't be pinned to edge of screen

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I pinned a UIImageView to 0 in all four directions, but it stays the same and doesn't pin to the edges, how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive, maybe add a picture if you are using storyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can to resolve it by Using Reset to suggested constraints Easily.How about dragging UIImageView edges to main UI edges and then reset to suggested constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I bet it has something to do with your **content mode** of the `UIImageView`. Try changing it in your storyboard or in code and find a style that suits your need.